# How can I access this PUBLIC picture via Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Here is a public photo post on Facebook:
https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=644875368952726
(Please ignore the content, this is just an example that came up in my testing)

I am unable to access this object in any way from the Graph API. The fbid seems to be 644875368952726 but trying to access 
https://graph.facebook.com/644875368952726
fails with an error using version 1.0, 2.0, or 2.1.

I cannot seem to find any way to access this photo via Graph. I'm using the tester and requesting a token with ALL permissions, logged in as myself. What am I missing?

I am creating a process that tracks likes, shares, and comments on individual posts, photos, etc. This is an example given to me that does not work, and I'm trying to figure out why. For most other objects, I am able to get the count of each data point I want to track. But not this one.

Comment: My guess is that you have not access to API v1.0 and API v2.0 and v2.1 require that you add an access token in the request

Comment: I am obviously passing an access token. I am using the Graph API Explorer at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ to do testing, and requesting a token with full access. I have even tried multiple applications.

Comment: Then I would guess that the user that posted that posted have turned on Facebook Platform

Comment: Is there any way to know if a user has turned off Platform? Or is that just a guess? I didn't realize that removed from them from Graph access also.

Comment: Do you have an access token from that user or one of their friends? Just because you can see something on facebook.com doesn't mean your app can access it via the API

Comment: No there is no way to know. But if you only use the API to get information instead of taking a random id from www.facebook.com you will not have any problem